# Embedded PDF works locally, not live

Tags: pdf

So I'm using the below code:

```
   <object data="my.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="800">
  <p>Your web browser doesn't have a PDF plugin.
  Install the missing plugin or you can <a href="my.pdf">click here to
  download the PDF file.</a></p>
   </object>
```

Which is working perfectly locally but when I upload it all I get is a grey screen (in Chrome). Has anybody faced this before / resolved it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the browser is attempting to load my.pdf and you have not specified where the browser should fetch that resource from.

I believe the steps that are happening behind the scenes in this scenario are:

1. Browser sees object tag and looks at mime-type
2. Browser searches for mime-type in loading plugins
3. Selected plugin loaded into that area of the dom
4. Plugin told to load the resource my.pdf
5. Plugin cannot find my.pdf on the clients computer
6. Plugin will display empty container

Try putting the full reference to the file. eg: http://my.server.domain/files/my.pdf

Comment: Thanks Wayne, but adding in the full reference didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with pdf object on latest Chrome (Version 33.0.1750.152) and latest OSX. Got around it by using iframe. However, not all pdf options work: page works; zoom and fit do not. At least the pagemode=t brings the toolbar up immediately, and then the user can manipulate the zoom and fit, so it's useable. My HTML:

```
<div class="responsive-container">
  <iframe src="./pdf/filename.pdf#pagemode=t"></iframe>
</div>
```